# Can I get a history of all Powerbuilder objects?

Tags: version-control, cvs, powerbuilder, last-modified

I am currently using PowerBuilder 12.0 (not my choice) and a bug seems to have crept in around a certain date. I know that you can take a single PowerBuilder item - say, a datawindow, window or menu - and call up "Show History" for it. Is it possible to do this for all of the items and then refine the date range yourself?

Comment: Which Version control system are you using?

Comment: Version 12.1 Build 6518

Comment: I am asking about PowerBuilder Version. I am asking which Version control system are you using? Version control system (Git, Subversion, VSS etc.) Which one are you using?

Comment: Oh, sorry, misunderstanding. You'll have to forgive me if my answer is weak here but I think answer you want is Windows 7 running PB12 through PushOK CVSSCC.

Comment: If using version control, it depends on the system, you could try right clicking the objects in PB and see if there's a "Show History..." menu item or something to that effect. On TFS, it opens a dialog and lets you look at all the check-in's for the object and you can select two and compare the differences. Or you could to similar via your CVS admin application I'm sure, but forgot CVS already getting older.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when using an 'external' source control tool from within PowerBuilder you can right click on the item in the library painter and there should be an option to 'view history'.  If you don't have that or a similar option you would need to launch the source control tool itself, navigate to the project/library which contains the PB object you want and then view its history from there.  You should also be able to compare the old version with the current one so you can identify what has changed.

Comment: This sounds like an item-by-item answer, which is what I was trying to avoid. The whole project is made by multiple people - myself included - and I am after any items modified within a specific date range.

Comment: Some source control systems support such a search but I don't know about CVS.

Comment: Your CVS admin program must have a way to look at recently changed objects. Or look to see where the items are stored, the PB exported files and maybe by looking at dates you could get short list of recently changed objects. Matt is right on about how to look at changes though.